# ServiceWorker claiming late in the lifecycle to use client.navigate in notificationclick event handler

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have a firebase serviceworker that shows notifications when a message is pushed from Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

It also publishes a post so that my React App can update accordingly.

```js
/* eslint-env worker */
/* eslint no-restricted-globals: 1 */
/* global firebase */
/* global clients */

import config from './config'

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js')

const { FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID } = config

firebase.initializeApp({ messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID })
const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload => {
  const title = payload.data.title
  const options = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    data: payload.data,
  }

  clients.matchAll({ includeUncontrolled: true }).then(clientz => {
    clientz.forEach(client => {
      sendMessageToClient(client, 'NEW_USER_NOTIFICATON')
    })
  })
  return self.registration.showNotification(title, options)
})

const sendMessageToClient = (client, message) => {
  const messageChannel = new MessageChannel()
  client.postMessage(message, [messageChannel.port2])
}
```

This all works fine, but I have added it for context.

What I want to do is have a click function that focuses on the correct window/tab and navigates to a link that is passed to it. Or if the tab is not open, open a new window and go to the link.

This is the code I have so far, added to the above file.

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
  const clickedNotification = event.notification
  const link = clickedNotification.data.link
  clickedNotification.close()
  const promiseChain = self.clients.claim()
    .then(() => self.clients
      .matchAll({
        type: 'window',
      })
    )
    .then(windowClients => {
      let matchingClient = null
      windowClients.forEach(client => {
        if (client.url.includes(matching_url)) {
          matchingClient = client
        }
      })
      if (matchingClient) {
        return matchingClient.navigate(link)
          .then(() => matchingClient.focus())
      }
      return clients.openWindow(link)
    })

  event.waitUntil(promiseChain)
})
```

*So, I realise that the chained `navigate` and `focus` inside a `then` is probably bad practice, but for now, I am just trying to get it to work. Then I will try and come up with a clever solution.*

So the problem with my code is that the `clients.claim()` doesn't seem to be working. The `matchAll` doesn't return anything to the next `then`, the argument is an empty array.

I could simply add the `includeUncontrolled: true` option to the `matchAll`, but the `navigate` command only works on a controlled client instance.

If I try the often referenced [Google example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/windowclient-navigate/index.html) for claiming and navigation, it works fine:

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim().then(() => {
    // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/matchAll
    return self.clients.matchAll({type: 'window'});
  }).then(clients => {
    return clients.map(client => {
      // Check to make sure WindowClient.navigate() is supported.
      if ('navigate' in client) {
        return client.navigate('activated.html');
      }
    });
  }));
});
```

So I am stuck.
The serviceworker is activated immediately, so I assume that it claim a client at any point after that.

Have I fallen for a random ServiceWorker Gotcha?
Can the claim only be used and navigated to on the handling of an activation event?

I would appreciate any help available.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work.

But I thought it would be worth documenting my workaround.

I could not get `client.navigate` to work in the `notificationclick` event handler.

So instead I just sent a `postMessage` containing the URL to be picked up in my app to trigger the redirect there, without any client claiming anywhere.

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
  const clickedNotification = event.notification
  const link = clickedNotification.data.link
  clickedNotification.close()
  const promiseChain = self.clients.matchAll({
      type: 'window',
      includeUncontrolled: true,
    })
    .then(windowClients => {
      let matchingClient = null
      windowClients.forEach(client => {
        if (client.url.includes(matching_url)) {
          matchingClient = client
        }
      })
      if (matchingClient) {
        sendMessageToClient(matchingClient, { type: 'USER_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED', link })
        return matchingClient.focus()
      }
      return clients.openWindow(link)
    })

  event.waitUntil(promiseChain)
})

const sendMessageToClient = (client, message) => {
  const messageChannel = new MessageChannel()
  client.postMessage(message, [messageChannel.port2])
}
```